# Bash script print commands, but do not print echo command

Tags: bash, command-line, echo

I would like to write a bash script the prints the commands. But for readability purposes, I do not want it to print the echo commands. Unfortunately, I cannot find the correct settings for my bash script to achieve this. I need help?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Makes the bash script to print out every command before it is executed
set -v

echo "Cleaning test database"
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:drop
echo "************************************************************"
echo ""

echo "Setting up the test database"
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:setup
echo "************************************************************"
echo ""
```

The output looks like:

```
echo "Cleaning test database"
Cleaning test database
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:drop
echo "************************************************************"
************************************************************
echo ""


echo "Setting up the test database"
Setting up the test database
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:setup
```

As you can see it prints out all the commands including the echo command, which I do not want to see.

Comment: Maybe this?:  `| grep -v "echo "`

Comment: Would  a Makefile be appropriate for your task? It's a wildly different approach, but `make` echoes each command by default as it executes it, *unless* you prefix the command with @.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `trap DEBUG` instead of `set -v` as one option.

For example

```
#!/bin/bash


# Makes the bash script to print out every command before it is executed except echo
trap '[[ $BASH_COMMAND != echo* ]] && echo $BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG

echo "Cleaning test database"
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:drop
echo "************************************************************"
echo ""

echo "Setting up the test database"
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:setup
echo "************************************************************"
echo ""
```

Debug is executed after every command.
$BASH_COMMAND is currently running command.

> BASH_COMMAND
>   The command currently being executed or about to be executed, unless the shell is executing a command as the result of a trap, in which case it is the command executing at the time of the trap.

So the trap just checks if the last command did not start with echo and prints it.

Comment: Thx 123, it works great and I will use it.

It is an interesting approach which I had not thought about. I wonder if there are special options or settings for my problem.

Comment: @GerardoNavarroSuarez I don't think there are, but if you find any let me know!

Comment: thanks @123. What if I want to hide other prints, like "read -s ...". I couldn't find the correct || && syntax...

Comment: ohh, no dealing with || is required... this works: `trap '[[ $BASH_COMMAND != echo* ]] && [[ $BASH_COMMAND != read* ]] && echo $BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG`

Comment: I found that ´pwd´ is printed as ´pwd´ when using this DEBUG solution.
When using -x the actual value is printed.

I need to know the later.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks @123 !

To filter multiple strings from the DEBUG trap (not just echo commands), we can use regexp match too.

For example, to filter out any command that starts with "echo" or "read" or "if", I use:

```
trap '! [[ "$BASH_COMMAND" =~ ^(echo|read|if) ]] && echo $PS4$BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG
```

**Update:**

In order to show bash *${variable}* values expended, I now use:

```
trap '! [[ "$BASH_COMMAND" =~ ^(echo|read|if) ]] && \
cmd=`eval echo "$BASH_COMMAND" 2>/dev/null` && echo "$cmd"' DEBUG
```

Comment: You command works but it still prints echo messages. I have tired `trap '! [[ "$BASH_COMMAND" =~ ^(echo|read|if|sleep|confirm_and_exit_on_no|confirm|exit) ]] && \ 
 cmd=\`eval echo "$BASH_COMMAND" 2>/dev/null\` && echo ---- "$cmd" ----' DEBUG`

Comment: @abhiarora, note two things: The ^ char means it will look for the begining of a line only, so if the echo is not at the beginning of a line, it will print it. Also note the \ char, it is required only if you break a long line in bach script, so remove it if you you dont use multiline for this script.